# Getting an error using gulp

Tags: gulp

I'm picking up an error with gulp on Windows 10

Running gulp through git bash works fine, it opens the current project in a new browser tab, but the moment I alter the style.scss file, and save it in atom, this error comes up...

```
    [17:02:54] Starting 'css'...

events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `&gt; 1%`
    at C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\dev-project\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:164:11
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolve (C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\dev-project\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:132:18)
    at browserslist (C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\dev-project\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:224:16)
    at Browsers.parse (C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\dev-project\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:61:16)
    at new Browsers (C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\dev-project\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:52:30)
    at loadPrefixes (C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\dev-project\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:70:24)
    at plugin (C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\dev-project\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:81:24)
    at LazyResult.run (C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\dev-project\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:277:20)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\dev-project\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:192:32)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it

Seen as though I am using Chrome, it was creating a conflict in /node_modules/browserlist/index.js

I edited %1 and took out firefox and added:

```
// Default browsers query
browserslist.defaults = [
  '> 5%'
]
```

I then also had to change gulpfile to correspond with the following task:

```
// CSS via Sass and Autoprefixer
gulp.task('css', function() {
    return gulp.src(scss + '{style.scss,rtl.scss}')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({
        outputStyle: 'expanded',
        indentType: 'tab',
        indentWidth: '1'
    }).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(postcss([
        autoprefixer('> 5%')
    ]))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write(scss + 'maps'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(root));
});
```

Here's the [source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserslist) if anyone encounters an issue like this